# convertir string a Double para sacar el subtotal

Tags: c#

soy nuevo en c# y tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
 using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()

    {

        int precio;
        int cantidadarticulo;
        int subtotal;
        int siniva;
        int coniva;
        int total;

     Console.WriteLine("dame nombre : ");
     string nombrepedido = Console.ReadLine();

     Console.WriteLine("dame precio : ");
     string preciopedidos = Console.ReadLine();
     precio = Convert.ToInt32(preciopedidos);


     Console.WriteLine("dame cantidad de cualquier articulo : ");
     string cantidadarticulopedido = Console.ReadLine();
     cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);


        //calcular subtotal
        subtotal = cantidadarticulo/16;
```

y si ven en este siguiente linea estoy usando toDouble para convertir un String a double para sacar el subtotal.

```
 cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);
```

para eso estoy usando el este codigo de c# :

```
Convert.ToDouble Method (String)
```

[origen del codigo anterior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx)

este es el codigo completo :

```
 //+===================================================================
//
//   Acerca del programa : 
//
//   3. Elabore un programa que pida el nombre, el precio y la cantidad de cualquier artículo (sin iva); 
//   y que después informe de cuanto tiene que pagar el usuario por dicho producto: subtotal sin iva, iva y total.  
//
//  Autor del codigo : Gilberto Quintero Armenta
//  codigo en github ( el codigo en linea ) :

//  Herramienta que use para codificar el codigo c# : https://dotnetfiddle.net
//
//
//
//
//
//+===================================================================

using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()

    {

        int precio;
        int cantidadarticulo;
        int subtotal;
        int siniva;
        int coniva;
        int total;

     Console.WriteLine("dame nombre : ");
     string nombrepedido = Console.ReadLine();

     Console.WriteLine("dame precio : ");
     string preciopedidos = Console.ReadLine();
     precio = Convert.ToInt32(preciopedidos);


     Console.WriteLine("dame cantidad de cualquier articulo : ");
     string cantidadarticulopedido = Console.ReadLine();
     cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);


        //calcular subtotal
        subtotal = cantidadarticulo/16;




        Console.WriteLine("subtototal: ");
        Console.WriteLine("sin iva: ");
        Console.WriteLine("total: ");



    }
}
```

no entiendo porque no funciona si en la documentacion indica que debo usar toDouble para convertir un string a Double,¿Dondre podria estar mi error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues es sencillo, te explico:

Estas declarando un entero

```
    int cantidadarticulo;
```

Estas tratando de asignar un double a un entero

```
     cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);
```

Para solucionarlo declara cantidadarticulo como double;

asi:

```
double cantidadarticulo;
```

Nota: Te sugiero declarar tus int como decimal, ya que por ejemplo un precio puede tener decimales. Asi como el subtotal

Comment: Para trabajar con precios (moneda) `double` no es el tipo correcto. El tipo adecuado es `decimal`, que no trabaja en coma flotante, `double` puede llegar a proporcionar errores por redondeo.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien tu duda ya ha sido aclarada, me gustaría añadir algunas sugerencias que te permitan escribir código en C# que sea más legible.

Para empezar, en C# no es común declarar las variables al inicio del `Main()`, como suele hacerse en C o C++, sino es una práctica común declarar las variables al momento de utilizarlas, como por ejemplo hiciste en la línea: `string nombrepedido = Console.ReadLine();`. De manera similar, en lugar de declarar al inicio del `Main()` la variable `int cantidadarticulo` y luego escribir:

```
Console.WriteLine("dame cantidad de cualquier articulo : ");
string cantidadarticulopedido = Console.ReadLine();
cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);
```

es más legible el siguiente código:

```
Console.WriteLine("dame cantidad de cualquier articulo : ");
string cantidadarticulopedido = Console.ReadLine();
int cantidadarticulo = Convert.ToDouble(cantidadarticulopedido);
```

Escribir de la anterior forma te hubiese hecho notar tu error de querer almacenar un `double` en un `int`, lo cual no está permitido. Si usas el VS incluso notarás que el programa se "queja" y te señala el error: "**No se puede convertir de manera implícita el tipo `double` en `int`**".

Por otro lado, es innecesario crear variables extras de tipo `string` para utilizar el método `Console.ReadLine()`. En lugar de escribir:

```
Console.WriteLine("dame precio : ");
string preciopedidos = Console.ReadLine();
precio = Convert.ToInt32(preciopedidos);
```

te sugiero que escribas de manera más sucinta el anterior código como:

```
Console.WriteLine("dame precio : ");
int precio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Lo anterior también es una práctica común en C#.

Para finalizar, con respecto al nombre de tus variables. Según tengo entendido, cuando el nombre de tu variable se compone de dos o más palabras, como es el caso de `cantidadarticulo`, no es recomendable escribirlo todo en minúsculas, sino más bien hacer uso del subguión `(_)` para separar cada palabra o capitalizar la primera letra de cada palabra a partir de la segunda. Por ejemplo, en el caso de la variable `cantidadarticulo`, es mejor escribir ya sea `cantidad_articulo` o `cantidadArticulo`.